# Cygwin fstab - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: mount, cygwin, fstab

I'm trying to automount my Windows home directory over my Cygwin home directory. If I run the mount command manually it works fine, but putting the mountpoint into /etc/fstab doesn't seem to work:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
<snip comments>
c:/Users/slim /home/slim/ binary,posix=0,user 0 0

$ mount c:/Users/slim
mount: can't find c:/Users/slim in /etc/fstab or in /etc/fstab.d/$USER

$ mount /home/slim/
mount: can't find /home/slim/ in /etc/fstab or in /etc/fstab.d/$USER

$ # ... and to demonstrate it works calling mount directly:
$ mount -obinary,posix=0,user c:/Users/hartnupj /home/hartnupj/
$ mount
C:/Users/hartnupj on /home/hartnupj type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user)
<snip>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your fstab entry is missing the (unused) third field for the filesystem type. Try this:

```
c:/Users/slim /home/slim/ ntfs binary,posix=0,user 0 0
```

(You could also set your Cygwin home directory to the Windows one in `/etc/passwd`.)