# Cygwin fstab configuration issue

Tags: linux, cygwin, fstab

Can't quite see where I'm going wrong. Trying to replicate the command "mount c: /c" in my fstab file, similar to this question: [Cygwin fstab - what am I doing wrong?](https://superuser.com/questions/450387/cygwin-fstab-what-am-i-doing-wrong/450884#450884)

```
Michael@Michael-PC ~
$ cat /etc/fstab
<comments etc>
c:/     /c      ntfs    binary,posix=0,user     0       0
cygdrive/c/     /c      none    bind

Michael@Michael-PC ~
$ ls /c

Michael@Michael-PC ~
$ mount c: /c

Michael@Michael-PC ~
$ ls /c
<stuff_i_want_with_a_mounted_c_drive>
```

I've tried 2 different methods of adding the required lines to fstab as outlined here: 
http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table

I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest simply creating a symbolic link inside Cygwin with /c pointing to /cygdrive/c.

Comment: good solution, I've been reading up on fstab recently so wanted to get to grips with it so I could learn more. +1 for pointing out what I was too obtuse to think of :) (EDIT, sorry, can't vote up yet on this site)

Comment: @MikeH-R, you can accept the answer. And I did the upvoting for you (OK, I'm lying, I'd have voted it up anyway).

Comment: sure, of course, I was hoping someone could solve the fstab issue as that's what I was interested in but a problem fixed is a problem fixed. Thanks everyone.